# Expand all categories of a Wikipedia category tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, wikipedia

I am trying to do this via the Web Console (using Firefox, but I am willing to change if necessary of course).

What I want to do is to basically click all the "plus" signs on a page at once. For an example see here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie:Volkswirtschaftslehre (excuse me for linking a german site, but the english wikipedia seems to be employing a different system now, and I need to do it on the German one...)

This is how far I have gotten: When I enter

```
var = document.getElementsByClassName("CategoryTreeToggle");
```

I get the variable test that includes all the elements of CategoryTreeToggle. However, apparently there is no onclick routine defined for those.

Can anybody please help me and tell me where to go from there?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi svick, it is for a research project about Wikipedia. To obtain a full dataset, we need to have all subcategories that are included in a specific category.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the whole category tree, I think a better idea would be to use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API). Specifically, [the `categorymembers` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which makes this easy:

```
$( '.CategoryTreeToggle' ).click();
```

Or, if you only want to click those toggles that are not already expanded:

```
$( '.CategoryTreeToggle[title="ausklappen"]' ).click();
```

But wouldn't it be easier to just use [CatScan](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/CatScan)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and accurate reply. Also thanks for pointing me to Catscan, I think this is what I will use from now on to do this.

Answer (score 0):

for English Wikipedia, you can type

```
$( '.CategoryTreeToggle[title="expand"]' ).click();
```